# Do I need both AMD and ATI Catalyst Control Center?

Tags: drivers, windows-10, amd-catalyst

I was browsing through some programs to remove, to save some disk space, and I found that I both have `AMD Catalyst Control Center` *and* `ATI Catalyst Control Center`.

Do I need both of them, and if not, which one do I get rid of? I guessed I could remove the ATI one, but looking at the dates, the ATI one was installed after the AMD one.

I am running Windows 10, should it matter. It seems like the AMD one was installed yesterday and the ATI one today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get them from?
If from Windows Update, then just go get the latest direct from AMD, should be Catalyst 15.7 - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

It ought to correctly overwrite any older drivers/control panel, etc

Just in case you weren't aware, AMD is just the new branding for ATI, which would imply the components labelled ATI would actually be older.

Comment: Windows Update indeed.